# What is the most simple way to delete parts of a string if you won't always know the length in python?

Tags: python, string

An example of this would be having a sentence with a set length `sentence1 = "How do you learn 21 code?"` then having a few more. ``` sentence2 = "Wow,coding is 4353 so much fun!"``sentence3 = ETC ```
The goal is to keep the important information and get rid of the rest allowing us to store it in a variable and call it a day.

So though there is a grammatical error in sentences it's because in my situation there is always the same amount of space between the first letter and the first number.

With that, I would love if anyone could answer this for me and tell me if there's any missing information.

Comment: I think your question is not very clear. COuld you please provide an example, say. what do you want to delete from your string(s)

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I get the feeling you're going to want to use string formatting. Check out the python docs or google python string formatting.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide a [mcve] including sample output, and _code_ for what you've tried so far

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here and tried explaining it. Though I think that one answer might work I'll try it for my problem and if it doesn't work I'll go more in-depth about what exactly I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to know the length. You could just replace the element with the empty string, like this:

```
sentence1 = 'How much do you 21 like to code?'
sentence1 = sentence1.replace('21 ', '')
print(sentence1)

How much do you like to code?
```